# how to change caption's position in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to have the caption of a bootstrap carousel at the bottom, with black background as wide as the browser. like this http://freebiesdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/boostrap-carousel.jpg

how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you already have a Bootstrap carousel working you could do something like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="yourimagebackground" alt="">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="carousel-caption">
            <p> your caption here</a>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

To set the background of your caption you could do this in your **css**

```
.carousel-caption {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 15px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

Here, `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);`  will set the background of the caption to a transparent black color. If you want it completely black you can just replace it by `background: black;` that's up to you!

Comment: thank you. it goes at the bottom but I can't mange to make it having the same width of the browser. How should I do that?

Comment: Could you edit you question and add the relevant code? Then i'll be able to further help you.